# Account name appears under app name in Android Market Place

Tags: android, google-play

I just released an update to my app in the android market place. I'm using my own personal account to release the app. Under the developer details I filled in my company details. In the market place underneath the app name, my personal name appears.

My client does not want to see this, so is there any way of removing it.

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not remove the publisher name.

But you can go to [developer account edit page](https://market.android.com/publish/editProfile) and change the *Developer Name* from your name to the company name.

Comment: THanks Sylarrr, that's what I'll do. The company name will look better than my name.